# Adding line break to javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, line-breaks

I'm trying to seperate a list with a line break but neither "\n" nor a br tag are working. Anybody know why?

```
var c_list=['One','Two','Three']
for (var x in c_list){
    holder_string += c_list[counter]
    holder_string += "\n"
    counter++
    $("#list").text(holder_string);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\n` isn't really showed in the browser, other than in the source, and `<br />` doesn't work in `text()` as it doesn't accept html, `html()` does

```
var c_list=['One','Two','Three']
for (var x in c_list){
    holder_string += c_list[counter]
    holder_string += "<br />"
    counter++
    $("#list").html(holder_string);
}
```

Note that you could just do

```
$("#list").html( c_list.join('<br />') );
```

Comment: dat answer speed... +1

Comment: `\n` shows up if the HTML element is `white-space: pre` -- which it probably isn't, given OP's issues.

Comment: @Blazemonger - Yeah, it also shows up inside `<pre>` tags and in a few other edge cases, but generally newlines and whitespace between tags makes no difference to layout.